# Core Service save component opaque

Tags: 2011, core-service

When I try to save a component using core service, the request works, but on the dashboard I find this :

[image]

And then, I have to save the component to be sure.

Here is the code I use :

```
using (var tridion = new CoreServiceAgent())
        {
            componentToCreate = tridion.Client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Component, ConfigurationContainerId) as ComponentData;
            componentToCreate.Title = itemNumber.ToString();
            componentToCreate.Schema = new LinkToSchemaData { IdRef = "tcm:179-277976-8" };

            schemaFields = tridion.Client.ReadSchemaFields("tcm:174-277976-8", true, new ReadOptions());

            Fields fields = new Fields(schemaFields, schemaFields.Fields, componentToCreate.Content, "Configuration");
            
            fields["Slogan"].AddValue(args.Settings.Slogan);

            componentToCreate.Content = fields.OuterXml;
            tridion.Client.Save(componentToCreate, new ReadOptions());
        }
```

CoreServiceAgent is a sort of "Facade" to the CoreServiceAgent.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because when you `Save` you are only creating a minor version of the component. If you call `tridion.Client.CheckIn` then you'll have a major version and it won't show like that (and it won't be checked out).

Even better, you could use the `tridion.Client.Create` method, which will save and checkin the new item.